# Wiring multiple ceiling fans/light kits and separate led ceiling pot lights to two separate switches

Tags: ceiling, fans

Added Image 8/30/23 that reflects the current wiring, devices and connection points.[image]
I am trying to fix an issue from an existing install in the new sunroom that was added to the exterior of the mobile home and did not accomplish what we were needing it to do electrical wise. We would like to have the current setup of two ceiling fans with lights and two pot lights (LED type) wired between two three way double switches, one on each end of the room. Currently, One of these switches gets the power from the panel and powers both fan/light sets (but not the pot lights). The power comes in with 14/2. There is 14-3 that leaves the box and guess was supposed to be power for the fans/light sets and the pot lights before going to the other switch. One of the fan/light is connected to 14-2 going to the 14-3 coming out of the powered switch box. This 14-3 then goes across the room to the other pot light and fan/light set. There is a 14-3 that comes from the other 3 way switch (non-powered) on the opposite side of the room. The light switch on this side only seems to control the one fan/light set on this side of the room although it is connected to the 14-3 that comes from the primary powered switch box that is also connected to the first fan/light. The two pot lights are not powered or connected to any powered line. The objective is to have both the fan/light sets to operate on one switch and the pot lights to operate on a separate switch in the same box using a double switch in each box.

Comment: Other than "evidently it needs to be completely re-wired from where power comes in" not much to say here since you seem less than clear about what's actually connected to what, and where things run, and without an accurate diagram it's not clear what was done wrong, and how to fix it now.

Comment: You have dual 3-way switches now, (4 total switches, 2 at each end of the room) or you intend to change to dual 3-ways? Your described wiring is far short of what dual 3-ways need to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How much rewiring are you willing to do?

Comment: @Ecnerwal My concern was the wiring was done all wrong to begin with and more would need to be done or replaced altogether but before I redo someone else work, I wanted to see possible options other than complete rewire since it would mean going into the wood ceiling and wood walls.  (Would attach a diagram but have not found a way to do that.).  There is currently only a single three-way switch at each switch box.

Comment: @Bill when you [edit] your question, there is a "sun and mountains" icon along the top of the edit box to add a picture.